# There is no getter for property named 'tablename' in 'class java.lang.String'

Tags: java, mybatis

I got the error `There is no getter for property named 'tablename' in 'class java.lang.String'` when I'm using mybatis.

My mapper xml is like this:

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.mapper.BasicMapper">
    <update id="dropTable" parameterType="String">
        DROP TABLE ${tablename}
    </update>
</mapper>
```

The interface is like this:

```
public interface BasicMapper {
    void dropTable(String tablename);
}
```

I use it in this way:

```
public void dropTable(String tablename) {
    basicMapper.dropTable(tablename);
}
```

I tried to replace `${tablename}` with `#{tablename}`, but it didn't help. How can I make it work?

Comment: You're supposed to pass a custom Object of a class with a `tablename` property. Otherwise, how would you pass multiple values, e.g. `firstName`, `LastName`, etc to an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, I tried your method, and it worked. But I'm wondering if there's a way to just pass a String instance instead of an Object with a `tablename` property.

Comment: Don't know. You'd have to read the MyBatis documentation to see if it can do that.

Comment: For just passing string, follow whatever you have done above and add @Params("tableName") in the call. also always preferrable to us # instead of $

Answer (score 6):

Use the following annotation for parameter:

```
public interface BasicMapper {
    void dropTable(@Param("tablename") String tablename);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to only pass a String object and use that name of the passed parameter as in the mapping function you need to use #{} instead of ${}, and it only works with function having one parameter.

Such as:

```
List<ItemMeta> getItemMetaByName(String itemName);
```

with mapping as:

```
<select id="getItemMetaByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="itemMapper">
        select * from ItemMeta where name like #{itemName}
</select>
```

The following mapping will throw the exception metioned:

```
<select id="getItemByName" parameterType="String" resultMap="itemMapper">
            select * from ItemMeta where name like ${itemName}
</select>

org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'itemName' in 'class java.lang.String'
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.Reflector.getGetInvoker(Reflector.java:377)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaClass.getGetInvoker(MetaClass.java:167)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.getBeanProperty(BeanWrapper.java:149)
```

Answer (score 2):

use `${_parameter}` instead of `${tablename}`

Comment: Hello hewei, and welcome to stack overflow; your code suggestion might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.mapper.BasicMapper">
<update id="dropTable" parameterType="string">
    DROP TABLE ${tablename}
</update>
```

use "string" not "String"
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeAliases 
javatype "String" alias as "string" in mybatis.

Comment: using string also doesnt work in this case. The only thing that worked for me was using @Params("tableName") while defining the call in interface.

Answer (score 0):

when your parameterType is "string", use `${value}` instead of `${tablename}`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and tried all the solutions given here. Only thing that worked for me was:

- Using @Param("tableName") in the interface.
- Using a object class to pass parameter but that works when you have multiple arguments to pass. if you only want to pass one single string, the above works.